# comparing 2 objects

Tags: c#, equality, comparator

I was wondering how you compare two objects for different values. What do i need to research to accomplish this? Is it a comparator and if so could someone point me to a good tutorial?

For example i want to see if 2 forms differ via their content (2 contact details form with 2 different sets of contact data, both have the same getType().Name but have different contents.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test for *equality*, then the way to go is have `SomeType` implement [`IEquatable<SomeType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) and do the comparison in the [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) method (which is what you would call to test for equality, obviously).

If you want to *order the values*, then the corresponding interface is [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).

There are code examples if you follow the links.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `IComparable` interface to allow comparisons between two objects. [Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can impliment IComparable on both forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

This will let you set how these classes are compared.